# Cancellation async in IDisposable class

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, idisposable

In my project I use a manager to control a plugin. The main idea is that this plugin must work only in single thread in multythreads WPF application. There is only one instance of plugin in PluginController.

So when I call Start method: it stops plugin (if running) and start it with new argument. Few times a second plugin notificate caller about it's state, and ViewModel shows it in the WPF window.

When I call method Start some times one after one, i see that the previous instance of ViewModel is not destroyed, but only sleeps after Stop. And it calls Update method as god as a new one instance. So my interface twiches becouse two instances are updating it's state. In log is see alternately lines from first one and second one.

But when I call Start(...) then Stop() and then Start(...) again everything works fine.

So

```
SomeManager.Start(...);
SomeManager.Start(...);
```

works with errors. And

```
SomeManager.Start(...);
SomeManager.Stop();
SomeManager.Start(...);
```

works fine. Can anybody explain me my mistake?

Down lied simplified code.

```
public static SomeManager 
{
    public static void Start(SomeArg arg)
    {
         Stop(); // forgotten code
         var vm = GetMainPageVM();
         vm.SomeVM = new SomeViewModel(arg);
         vm.SomeVM.StartCommand.Execute(null);
    }
    public static void Stop()
    {
         var vm = GetMainPageVM();
         if (vm.SomeVM != null)
         {
             vm.SomeVM.Stop();
             vm.SomeVM.Dispose();
             vm.SomeVM = null;
         }
    }
}  

public sealed SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDisposable
{
    private readonly Guid _guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    private IPlugin _plugin;        
    private SomeArg _arg;

    public ICommand StartCommand {get; }
    public CancellationTokenSource Source {get; }   

    public SomeViewModel(SomeArg arg)
    {
        this._arg = arg;
        this._plugin = PluginController.GetPluginByName("SomePlugin");
        StartCommand = new RelayCommand(StartAsync);
    }

    ~SomeViewModel()
    {
       Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
       Dispose(true);
       GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    { ... }

    private async Task StartAsync()
    {
        var progress = new Progress<ISomeProgress>(Update);

        try
        {
            await StartImplementationAsync(progress).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { ... }
    }

    private async Task StartImplementationAsync(Progress<ISomeProgress> progress)
    {
        var result = await this._plugin.startAsync(
            this._arg,
            progress,
            this.Source.Token
        ).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
       this._plugin.Stop(); 
    }

    private void Update() {log.Debug($"this._guid" ....); } 
}

public sealed SomePlugin: IPlugin
{
   public async Task<SomeResult> StartAsync(SomeArg args, IProgress<SomeProgress>, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   { ... } 

   public void Stop() { ... } 
}
```

UPDATE: I think the problem in simple words is : how to correctly cancel async operation in IDisposable object in normal case with CancellationTokenSource.Cancel() and in unnormal case when Dispose() or Finalizer is called

Comment: When you call the `Stop()` method, it calls `SomeVM.Stop()`. So this stops the second view model from updating its state (I suppose). In the `Start()` method, this already existing view model's `Stop()` method is not being called, so the view model stays active. What is not clear to you?

Comment: Sorry, i have misspelled when I simplified my code. In first line of Start() method I call Stop()

Comment: After I added Thread.Sleep(50); after Stop(); everything works fine in any case.